# access outlook mail server using java

Tags: java, email

I want to access my enterprise outlook account mounted on a server using java program.. already tried JAMES.. but it does not look to be the right option.. any suggestions (using java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) API? It has different options to connect to an Exchange server:
http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/Third_Party.html